# jQuery autocomplete of countries along with the lists from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, jquery-autocomplete

As my requirement, getting auto suggestion values along the total number of list from the database.

For Ex: if I type "Lon", on loading it's should display as London,United Kingdom(60 properties) where 60 is the dynamic values and the total list in the London location from the database.

For Reference: http://www.wimdu.com/

In this  site search option auto suggestion exactly I need.

How could I get the auto suggestion values like this?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP, fetch data from the database and do

```
json_encode($data);
```

Use jQuery AJAX to read this data. And then use [jQuery UI Autocomplete Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: You need to first fetch the data using PHP. If you are using MySQL, make sure to use `ILIKE` to match the results. Then use this result in AJAX and apply the jQuery plugin mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options available. You can also look for Twitter `typeahead.js`

Check for NBA and NHL Teams example, hope this suffice.

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/